# How to detect the break over voltage for a contactor

Tags: ac, contactor

I want to determine at what voltage will a contactor fail.

My idea was to either send an impulse or vary the AC power across a contactor. The contractor will be in the open state the entire time. Below is the contactor, the test is only applied on one pole.

[image]

The Test point label should in theory never see any voltage, since the contactor is open. However, by increasing the AC voltage, there will be a point where the AC voltage will break over and the voltage seen at the Test point will increase.

How do I make a test, that is able to monitor the Test point and light up an LED when there is voltage present at the Test point?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWSFp9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: This will be a moving value, humidity for one will cause it to change.